# A value larger than ULong? Computing 100!

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, math

I'm trying to compute 100! and there doesn't seem to be a built-in factorial function.  So, I've written:

```
Protected Sub ComputeFactorial(ByVal n As ULong)
        Dim factorial As ULong = 1
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 1 To n
            factorial = factorial * i
        Next
        lblAnswer.Text = factorial
    End Sub
```

Unfortunately, running this with the value of 100 for n rseults in

> Value was either too large or too
>   small for a UInt64.

So, is there a larger data type for holding numbers?  Am i mistaken in my methods?  Am I helpless?

Comment: Why don't you take the opportunity and write a bigint class yourself? It's a bit more in the spirit of the Euler Project... :)

Comment: For the record:  
100! ~= 9.33262154 × 10^157

Comment: @Guffa if i only knew where to start, hahah

Comment: It's not actually all that hard to implement a bigint class.

You could even implement multiplication by repeated addition, if all you need is 100!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like Project Euler.

.NET 4.0 has System.Numerics.BigInteger, or you can pick up a pretty sweet implementation here:
[C# BigInteger Class](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/biginteger.aspx)

Edit: treed :(

I'll add - the version at CodeProject has additional features like integer square root, a primality test, Lucas sequence generation. Also, you don't have direct access to the buffer in the .NET implementation which was annoying for a couple things I was trying.

Comment: Indeed, Project Euler!  I suppose I'll have to go with one of these other classes.  Quite unfortunate!

Comment: Don't be upset - I was using the one from CodeProject when I put down some 80 problems in 7 days. I stopped shortly after - stupid ADD. :o

Answer (score 1):

Until you can use [`System.Numerics.BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(VS.100).aspx) you are going to be stuck using a non-Microsoft implementation like [`BigInteger` on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/biginteger.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use an array to store the digits of the number. You can tell by inspection that the result will not have more than 200 digits.

Answer (score 0):

You need an implementation of "BigNums". These are integers that dynamically allocate memory so that they can hold their value.

A version was actually [cut from the BCL](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2008/01/04/where-did-biginteger-go-melitta-andersen.aspx).

The J# library has an implementation of [java.math.BigInteger](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) that you can use from any language.

*Alternatively*, if precision/accuracy are not a concern (you only care about order of magnitude), you can just use 64-bit floats.

Answer (score 0):

decimal will handle 0 through +/-79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335 with no decimal point(scale of zero)

Comment: Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal.